# How do I disable internal redirect handling for NextJS and let the browser handle it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I'm writing a toy example for basic cookie/magic link authentication.

The flow goes something like this:

1. If the the auth token cookie is missing from the request when sending requests to a protected path, then inside the `getServerSideProps` for those paths, it redirects them to `https://myapp.com/auth/login`, where they can request a magic link
2. Click on the magic link `https://myapp.com/auth/login?token=AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE`
3. Inside `getServerSideProps` for the login page, I extract `AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE` from query params and send it to an API server to check if it is valid
4. If it is, then set it as an HttpOnly cookie in the response and redirect to the home page `https://myapp.com/`, a protected path

The section of code which deals with setting the cookie and redirecting looks like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    // code extracting AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE and sending it to backend API
    context.res.writeHead(307, {
        "Set-Cookie": // the HTTP only cookie containing AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE,
        Location: "https://myapp.com/"
    }).end()
    
    return  { props: {} };
}
```

Ideally, this would result in the NextJS app sending the browser an empty response that only contains those two headers. The browser would receive and save the auth cookie, and then redirect to `https://myapp.com/`. The redirected request will now have the auth cookie and succeed in going to `https://myapp.com/`.

Strangely, however, when I test it, the page I end up on is `https://myapp/auth/login`. The first thing I did is check if the redirect happened at all (by console logging in the `getServerSideProps` of the appropriate pages), and sure enough, it did. It first hit the `/auth/login?token=AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE` endpoint, then the `/` endpoint, then the `/auth/login` endpoint.

The next thing I did was check if the cookie was set, and sure enough, it was (I checked in the Application tab of DevTools). In fact, if I subsequently, MANUALLY navigated to `https://myapp.com/`, it did not redirect me back to `/auth/login` since I had the authentication cookie.

I also tested if browser-side redirecting can even be done in such a manner, and sure enough, it can.

When running the following code inside `getServerSideProps`:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    // other code
    context.res.writeHead(307, {
        Location: "https://example.com/?test=true"
    });

    return { props: {} };
}
```

It in fact DID redirect me, browser-side, to `https://example.com/?test=true`. This suggests to me that NextJS checks if it CAN perform an internal redirect (by checking the hostname of the `Location` header probably) and if it can, it does.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour and let the browser do the redirecting? Because for my application, I NEED the browser to be doing the redirecting, or else there won't be the authentication cookie that I need in the redirected request.

## Update:

It seems my issue had nothing to do with NextJS but rather the cookie policy. I set my cookies to `SameSite=strict`. This meant whenever I clicked on a link from Gmail for example, the auth cookies did not get sent. When I tested it by pasting the link directly, everything worked just how I expected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the update, this issue had nothing to do with NextJS but rather the cookie policy. I set my cookies to `SameSite=strict`.
This meant whenever I clicked on a link from Gmail for example, the auth cookies did get set but did not get sent along with the redirected request. When I tested it by pasting the link directly, everything worked just how I expected it.